Shrinkage estimators outside MVO? Sample mean or James-Stein estimator?
Generic question: Are there any uses of Shrinkage estimators, such as James-Stein estimator for mean or Ledoit-Wolf estimator for covariance matrix outside mean-variance optimization (MVO) framework? I've never seen shrinkage estimators usage in finance, aside from MVO. Below, I specify a specific problem, which might utilize JS estimator, but not sure if it is acceptable for practitioners.
Specific question: Suppose we have $n\geq3$ financial time series (correlated or uncorrelated) for stocks (e.g., 10 different time series of returns of $n$ stocks, each with $T$ observations). The goal is to estimate mean of each financial time series, i.e., $\hat{\mu}_{i}$, $i=1,2,...n$.
Apparently, the most straightforward approach would be to compute for each series sample mean, i.e., $\hat{\mu}_{i}=\frac{x_1+x_2+...x_T}{T}$, where $i=1,2,...n$. However, James-Stein estimator suggests that if $n\geq3$, then it is better to pool together all these $n$ financial time series, and then estimate mean vector collectively.
What approach would you use and why? James-Stein result is kind of counterintuitive, but as far as I understand it produces more reliable results.

This could probably work just as well on Cross Validated as here. Not saying you should move it there, only sharing the thought.

Agree. As I am interested to get response from financial practitioners, probably it is better to keep it here. If I don't get an answer(s), I'll move it to Cross Validated.

Sane: The estimation of a mean of a series is so notoriously difficult that my experience is that the use of the james stein estimator for the context you described is probably limited.  That's just my experience of course. Note that the approach could possibly be used to smooth out the return matrix in an MV optimization ( the idea being: "we can't estimate the returns with any precision so let's make them all similar" ) so my experience doesn't necessarily mean its not used.

If I understood correctly, James-Stein is mostly used in the context of mean-variance optimization, James-Stein use is somewhat limited outside this context, such as mean estimation for the sake of mean estimation, right?

that's what my guess would be. To be honest, I haven't seen it in MV optimization either but I'm confident that it's used because it's a nice way to decrease the "sensitivity" of MV optimization to the estimation of returns. For straight estimation of returns outside of MV opt, my guess is no. I would google for "james stein estimation in MV optimization".

Here's one. But, the same question arises: It's an interesting result and people then stand on Stein's shoulders and write papers with nice applications or variants. Are they used in the real world ? We don't know. https://cdar.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/kercheval.pdf

yes, there are many applications within MVO framework, but I am not aware of any outside of this. In the link that you provided, again MVO is mentioned.

Sane: There may be risk management applications also but I have no experience in that area.
